# How way to load all of my web applications in a web application that i'm working to?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, web

[image]

Hi, I'm newbie Web Developer.
This is my case:

I have 3 web applications.
At the moment I am developing one another to load all of my web apps.
You can look at the picture.
When I click "button A", so it can load "App A" in red area (I guess i will do it with Ajax), if you have better alternative please tell me.

Comment: You should look into AngularJS if you haven't already. CodeSchool has a good course on it which includes how to make tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Say you had the following markup with the following jQuery code... you could change the `src` attribute of the `iframe` to different sites:

```js
$("#b1").click(function(){
  $("#target").attr("src","https://jquery.com/")
});
$("#b2").click(function(){
  $("#target").attr("src","https://nodejs.org/en/")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b1">site1</button>
<button id="b2">site2</button>
<iframe id="target"></iframe>
```

Quite a few sites (including SO) now prevent their content from being loaded into a frame, so YMMV.

Comment: It doesn't work bro.
Are you sure we can use attr in this case? I use container to show my web application (red area in the picture).

Answer (score 0):

If you whant to use modern teknologies, think you can use angularjs, it's pritty good in many cases of front end development.

For you case you can use angular angular routing for loading different views on menu click. Check this out:

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

But start from first tutorial. After you have done it ones you are not 'newbie' any more :)